# What if we don't emit event in smartcontract

Tags: solidity, erc20, bep20

In ERC20 interface, there are 2 events to be implemented.  ​

`event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);`

`event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);`

What if we actually implement transfer and approve functions but never emit the events. Will transaction still appear on bscscan or etherscan, or will it be a quiet transaction that only transactor knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BscScan and EtherScan use the `Transfer()` event to update their statistics of token holders and to display amount of tokens transfered in the transaction detail page.

If you don't emit the event, it

- wouldn't display the "Tokens Transferred" field in the [transaction detail](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x32ffcc6ff3f5b63abd6a1b9152d6faf1596b99f8f67922c307047e55b332fea8) page
- wouldn't update the token balance of the sender and receiver on Etherscan (e.g. on their [address detail](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdd28d6b5e1e366ec12842807acdb908f1321b08b) page)

But the contract would still transfer the tokens, and Etherscan would still show the [transaction detail](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x32ffcc6ff3f5b63abd6a1b9152d6faf1596b99f8f67922c307047e55b332fea8) page (just without the tokens data).

Comment: Thanks. Also, will it show on transfers tab in the big table below? https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7

Comment: This table is also listing the `Transfer()` events. So if you don't emit the event, it won't be in the table.